# How to hide hyperlinks subreports from main reports in printing

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, sapb1

I'm using crystal reports for SAP BUSINESS ONE and I want to hide hyperlinks subreports from main reports just when I print it.

The hyperlink to hide (`Situation(2).rpt`):
[image: hyperlink at bottom of page]

Thank you!

Comment: whether it is normal print or color print

Comment: It does not matter

Comment: change font color to blue and remove the underline from hyperlink text

Comment: Oh thank you! it could be a solution, and if my client prints it in black and white have you a solution to propose me?